# How do I configure Wordpress to manage my website with a blog as a part of that website?

Tags: wordpress

WP version: 3.1.1 
Theme: Twenty Ten

I am new to WP. I am not new to PHP, MySQL or Apache (but I don't consider myself an expert in any of these). I want to use WP as the foundation for my website. The layout is very simple. Every page should have a navigation menu that looks like this:

`[Home] [About] [Projects] [Blog]`

with every element being a static WP Page except for `Blog`.

Here are the issues I'm running into:

1. **I am not able to add the blog into the navigation menu.** I am able to create a Menu and add Pages to it, but I don't know how to add a link to my blog to it. I suspect it's because WP is treating the entire website as a blog and that the Pages are some sort of special case; I don't know if this is the right way to think about WP.
2. **Each Page has an area for comments.** Do I need to roll my own theme (i.e. edit the loop-page.php template) to get rid of this? This is my first reaction to this issue. I was just wondering if there was a way to do it from the GUI. As I look at customizing (e.g. remove the search field, get rid of the categories on static pages, etc.), in general, it seems like the way to do it is to edit the theme itself; is this the right solution for this problem?

I've done the following:

1. Looked on http://codex.wordpress.org/. I can't find a way for WP to manage my whole website but not treat the entire website like a blog. Ideally I'd like the URLs to look something like: `http://website.com/about`, `http://website.com/home`, `http://website.com/blog/2011/04/firstpost`, etc.
2. Did the customary Google and search here on SO. I didn't find anything relevant. It seems that most folks want to go the other way: They have a pre-existing website and are trying to integrate WP as a subset of that website.

The current state of my installation is here: http://ootbdev.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Look into making your *blog* section separate. Under Administration -> Settings -> Reading you can adjust how your blog functions and where it lives. Check out the codex for making your [front page a static page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page).
2. Comments can be turned off on a Post by Post basis. See Administration -> Posts -> Edit

The TwentyTen theme should do everything you want. It is pretty flexible. That's why it's the default. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are right, WP treats the whole webpage as a blog and considers pages to be a special case. If you want a link to your blog in the menu (and the theme doesn't offer that functionality), you have to hardcode it yourself. However, in the settings you can specify which page, if any, to display initially.

The settings offer options to change the appearance of the URLs as well. If these options don't suit your needs, consider using mod_rewrite via `.htaccess`.

More generally speaking, there's nothing that prevents a theme author from ignoring your settings, so depending on your desired theme, you may have to alter it yourself.